# Could not build module

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

After Xcode update to v. 5.0.2 i can't build my app for iOS 6.0 target.
I can build only for iOS 7.0

I get many errors:

```
Could not build module CoreFoundation
Could not build module Darwin
Cyclic dependency in module Darwin: Darwin -> Foundation -> CoreFoundation -> Darwin
Could not build module Foundation
```

Interesting thing, is that before the update it was possible to compile the app for iOS 6.0, **BUT** I had the same errors when trying to compile app for iPhone 4/4S

PS. Build Settings - armv7, armv7s. **Without arm64.**

Comment: Fixed! But...I don't know how I do it...

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue.
Solved it by following:

Go to `Build settings` -> `Apple LLVM 7.0 - Language - Modules` -> `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` and switch it to NO for debug and release.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem by moving my `Header Search Paths` settings to `User Header Search Paths`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by making my Header Search Paths non-recursive instead of recursive.